# How to use Go-To Action Buttons?

Tags: html, email, gmail

Can someone tell me the markup for Go-To Action button in email intro?

[image]

The button is not in the email, but it provides a quick link before even opening the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the quick action buttons in gmail. From the google developer site the button you have shown is called a Go-To Action. The following link has some markup examples depending on the action such as 'view' or 'track'.
[Email Markup-Go To Actions](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/go-to-action)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just scan the email for hyperlinks thus creating a dynamic hyperlink in the email row. For that specific button I would check out Google's Material Design lib. https://material.io/icons/